# Pexpect and Terminal Resizing

Tags: terminal, resize, pexpect

I'm using pexpect to automate ssh-ing into a remote server that prompts for a password. The process is very simple, and works great:

```
child = pexpect.spawn("ssh -Y remote.server")
child.expect(re.compile(b".*password.*"))
child.sendline(password)
child.interact()
```

This works great, however, I notice one quite annoying quirk I have not been able to figure out. When I use vim in this terminal, it seems to not resize correctly. When ssh-ing directly, and using a program such as vim, I can resize my terminal window (locally), and the remote program automatically/interactively fixes the columns and lines. My pexpect instance does not. There are a few other minor quirks that I can lvie with, but this one is quite annoying.

I'm hoping to find a way I can get my pexpect ssh session to behave the same way a native ssh session does, or at the very least understand the reason the two behave differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually an example for this under the `interact()` function in [pexpect's doc](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/index.html). Just like writing `C` code, it requires a `SIGWINCH` handler.

```
import pexpect, struct, fcntl, termios, signal, sys

def sigwinch_passthrough (sig, data):
    s = struct.pack("HHHH", 0, 0, 0, 0)
    a = struct.unpack('hhhh', fcntl.ioctl(sys.stdout.fileno(),
                                          termios.TIOCGWINSZ , s) )
    global p
    p.setwinsize(a[0], a[1])

# Note this 'p' global and used in sigwinch_passthrough.
p = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash')
signal.signal(signal.SIGWINCH, sigwinch_passthrough)

p.interact()
```

Comment: Wow, I should RTFM, right in front of me. I honestly have very little understanding of how the system was running, I was not looking in the right part of the documentation. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The `SIGWINCH` handles window size change. If you need it behave the same of native ssh, you should also set the pexpect initial window size:

```py
import pexpect, struct, fcntl, termios, signal, sys

def get_terminal_size():
    s = struct.pack("HHHH", 0, 0, 0, 0)
    a = struct.unpack('hhhh', fcntl.ioctl(sys.stdout.fileno(), termios.TIOCGWINSZ, s))
    return a[0], a[1]

def sigwinch_passthrough(sig, data):
    global p
    if not p.closed:
        p.setwinsize(*get_terminal_size())

p = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash')
# Set the window size the same of current terminal window size
p.setwinsize(*get_terminal_size())
# Hook the window change signal so that the pexpect window size change as well
signal.signal(signal.SIGWINCH, sigwinch_passthrough)

p.interact()
```

Comment: I see a strange behavior with this on tmux. I see a rectangle in the upper-left part of the screen that gets redrawn, while the area outside this rectangle shows static dotted lines.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bJom.png

Comment: This was fixed by force-detaching other connected clients with the -d flag